# Split two-value-to-one vector in one vector with two values in R

Tags: r

I am using the Rglpk package in R and i want to use the results. So I use i.e.

```
w<-Rglpk_solve_LP(obj, mat, dir, rhs, max = max)
```

Then the results are i.e.

```
$optimum
[1] 0.02142857
$solution
[1] 0.02142857 0.00000000
$status
[1] 0
$solution_dual
[1] 0.000000000 0.001298701
$auxiliary
$auxiliary$primal
[1] 0.02142857 0.02142857 0.02142857 0.02142857
$auxiliary$dual
[1] 0 0 0 1
```

When I want the first row I wrote

```
w[1]
```

and the result is

```
> w[1]
$optimum
[1] 0.02142857
```

but when I want to use below the

```
> w[2,2]
Error in w[2, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

while

```
> w[2]
$solution
[1] 0.02142857 0.00000000
```

Is there any any way (please) to separate this w[2] into w[2,1] and w[2,2].
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `w` is a list.  So we use `[[` to extract the `list` element

```
w[[2]][1]# for first element
w[[2]][2]# for second element
```

Or

```
w[2]$solution[1]
w[2]$solution[2]
```